# How to get imei number, mac address(or uid) of mobile device on adf mobile

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

I need to get imei number and mac address of device (supposed to be works on both android and iphone) on adf mobile. Actually, even if i could get the device uid(unique identifier key) can be useful for me. Any comments about uid for 2 platforms that valid are welcome
bgrds

Comment: My purpose is my mobile application to secure based on device

Answer (score 0):

// Device ID ;

```
android_id = Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

// Device IMEI ;

```
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String Imei = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 0):

webyildirim, As per my knowledge you need to get the device os name, then based on OS condition you achieve the IMEI number, already posted for andriod, this one for Ios. thanks

NSString *ImeiNum = [[NetworkController sharedInstance] IMEI];